# Sorting a custom ListView Adapter with multiple ArrayLists

Tags: android, android-listview

I've a custom ListView with 5 ArrayLists in the adaptor.

```
private ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> message = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Long> time = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> imageId = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> extras = new ArrayList<>();
```

`ArrayList` `time` contains remaining time in milliseconds. I want to display the list from lower to higher time left. If i just perform `Collection.sort` on a single ArrayList, others will remain unchanged. How can i sort all the ArrayLists accordingly with `time`.

I am passing all the ArrayLists to my custom adaptor at once.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are the arraylists having a one-to-one relationship to each other? If so create a data model for it, and sort by the time field, the others will follow accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I think better to create a new class like this

```
class Class {
   String name;
   String message;
   Long time;
   String imageId;
   String extras;
}
```

Then creating single ArrayList then you can sort it by any fields by creating Comparator you want